# How to run mvn jetty server with reset endpoints from within IntelliJ for debugging?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

> **Project Description**

I have a maven 3 project that runs java 8 exposing REST endpoints and runs on jetty and I use intellij v14.1.3 for an IDE

> **Current debugging method**

For debugging (stepping through code) I have to create a remote localhost:8000 config within Intellij and set it to run for local testing.  When testing I start up the server itself from command line as mvnDebug:

```
   $ mvnDebug clean jetty:run
```

then it conencts to my localhost:8000 within intellij and then I can set a break point and send a /GET request and the code breaks on my break points.

> **ASK**

How can I avoid using mvnDebug and just run the project from within Intellij itself like visual studio and just hit run and it runs as debug within Intellij (based on some config work perhaps) and debug from there instead of have to use mvnDebug as a hook into Intellij?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define new Maven 'Run Configuration'

```
Run -> Edit Configuration -> '+' -> Maven
```

and specify

- *Working Directory* - directory where you execute mvnDebug,
- *Command Line* - the command itself, i.e. 'clean jetty:run'
- Other relevant fields such as *Name*

After you've done this, you will see just created 'Run Configuration' in the toolbar and will be able to run or debug you code within IntelliJ by pressing corresponding toolbar button.

[image]

Comment: thx!  this is awesome! What about starting it up on a specific port?

Comment: also, when running the debug "start debug" in command toolbar it gave me an error: "[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "mvnDebug". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase"

Comment: fyi...changing "mvnDebug clean jetty:run" to "clean jetty:run" worked.  (y)

Comment: @JaJ Try to add following in the command line to run jetty on specific port: -Djetty.port=<PORT>, so the whole command should look like this: 'clean jetty:run -Djetty.port=8080'